# SwiftUI SF Symbols Button in NavigationBar not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use a button that is a SF Symbol Image as the trailing navigation bar item, however, when clicking the button on a REAL IPHONE, it's very very unreliable and I end up clicking it 30+ to only get 1 click registered.

My code looks like this:

```swift
NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Example")
            } .navigationBarTitle("Tasks").navigationBarItems(trailing:

            Button(action: { print("I was clicked!")}) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }

            )
}
```

However, when I put the same button outside of `navigationBarItems`, the button registers clicks much easier.

What can I do here?

Is this a problem with SwiftUI, if so, is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `padding` to the `image` to increase the hitbox of the image

```
Image(systemName: "plus")
    .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the padding doesn't effect its actual placement? Doing makes it easier to press on the side where leading padding is applied but remains difficult when clicking on the trailing side. I'd also like to be able to apply more padding, without it making the UI wonky.

Comment: Another solution is to add this modifier to the image: .font(.title)

Comment: You can also add the modifier .contentShape(Rectangle()) to preserve the size but have the hit box be a lot bigger.